"EADDRINUSE" Error when trying to deploy/build in Vercel
I'm using windows, I there's several solutions for linux but none for windows. 

I have no idea why this is happening, but it seems to be happening to everyone using the Vercel CLI and ExpressJS. However, adding the following into your root seems to be a workaround for some reason: process.on("uncaughtException", (error) => {   console.error("Uncaught Exception:", error); });
